# Strange behavior of 'char' pointers

Tags: c

When I declare and run the following it gives me a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

```
main()
{
    char *p = "boa";
    *(p+1) = 'y';
    printf("%s",p);
}
```

I suspect `char *p` is a constant, etc.

But the following works fine.

```
main()
{
    int i = 300;
    char *p = (char*)&i;
    *(p+1) = 'y';
    printf("%s",p);
}
```

What is the reason behind this? Doesn't the above rule apply to this as well?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your definition of "works fine". But the reason the assignment doesn't segmentation fault is because `p` was made to point to the address of the `i` variable, which is clearly not a constant. `i` was assigned a constant value, but `i` itself is not a constant.

For `i = 300` (assuming little endian [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)):

```
  +--+--+--+--+
i:|2c|01|00|00|
  +--+--+--+--+
  .
 /|\
  |

p:&i
```

After `*(p+1) = 'y'`

```
  +--+--+--+--+
i:|2c|79|00|00|
  +--+--+--+--+
  .
 /|\
  |

p:&i
```

So, the print statement just happens to print `,y` for you, but only because you relied on the platform's byte ordering (and that `2c` was a printable [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character). Things could have been different on a big endian machine, and/or if it was non-ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, boy...

The first one seg-faults due to the string being `const` (you've got that right). The second one, however, is a fascinating abuse of the pointer semantics! ;-)

Here's what you are doing in the second example:

- Have a random `int` number with a value (in your case - `300`)
- Get an address of that `int` - basically an address to a location that holds a (32-bit?) `int` of 300 and cast it to a `char*`, where each element points to an 8-bit value
- Get the address of the "first" 8-bit value, increment by one (increment by 8 bits(!)) and change the value of those 8 bits to a numeric ASCII code of 'y'
- Print the "resulting string"

Answer (score 1):

The difference is this:

```
char *p="boa";
```

`p` is a *pointer*. You are making `p` point at a string literal `"boa"` which cannot be modified and when you try to modify it a segfault occurs.

```
int i=300;
char *p=(char*)&i;
```

`i` is a variable of type `int`, you only use the constant `300` to initialize `i` and do a bitwise copy of the value of `300` into the location of `i`, but you are *never* pointing at the constant itself, just using it as an initializer. This is the difference, `p` in your first example points at a constant string literal, whereas in your second example it points at a variable of type `int`. Hence modifying the location of `i` later on with the pointer `p` is fine because you are modifying a non constant object `i`.